# Line Endpoint Detection

Tags: c#, line, ocr, detection, endpoint

I plan to detect endpoints of lines generated from characters (OCR) in C#. I want something like this:

[image]

What I mean by "endpoint" is I want to get the ends of any lines in the characters... for example a 'C' has two endpoints (one at the top and one at the bottom) as seen in the above image represented as a red pixel. I can extract the single lines from the "fatter" existing scanned characters, I can do edge detection and also Flood-fill analysis, but I can't seem to replicate the above! Any pointers to articles or existing code would be much appreciated! Any code samples will be fine as I can easily convert C++ or any .NET language to C#.

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a definition of "endpoint" yet, I suggest:

- A black point is an endpoint iif all neighbors (i.e. black points with manhattan distance <= 3) lie in a sector of less than 45 degrees.

Finding the angle to each neighboring black point should not be too difficult.  Sorting these angles and finding the range is also not difficult, although you need to be careful of the discontinuity (where the angle suddenly changes by 360 degrees).  It may be slightly faster to sort by slope without actually calculating angle.  An additional speedup can be obtained with early-exit logic.

Comment: Ok I'll update the question with a definition. Basically what I want to get is the ends of any lines... for example a 'C' has two endpoints (one at the top and one at the bottom) as seen in the above image represented as a red pixel. I also thought of scanning the entire line (because I have the pixels that are black already because I used a flood-fill algo to select the characters out of the PNG and then used a line thinning algo to thin it down to a single line) and searching for a black pixel that is surrounded by only ONE other black pixel (in ALL directions including diagonals).

Comment: @jduncanator: That definition isn't anywhere technical enough to actually use.  Plus, an endpoint may easily have two black neighbors, both on the same side.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it.
For every pixel witch is not 0 count the number of pixels not 0 in the 3 x 3 grid around this pixel. If the number is 2 you have a endpoint of a line.

```
// count the number of points in the neighborhood of our pixel
inline int countNeighborhood(cv::Mat &img, int xc, int yc)
{
    if (img.empty()) return 0;
    if (img.type() != CV_8UC1) return 0;
    xc++;
    yc++;
    int iCnt = 0;
    for (int y = yc - 2; y <= yc; y++)
    {
        if ((y < 0) || (y >= img.rows)) continue;
        uint8_t *buf = img.ptr(y);
        for (int x = xc - 2; x <= xc; x++)
            if ((x > 0) && (x < img.cols) && (buf[x])) iCnt++;
    }
    return iCnt;
}

/*  get endpoints of a image with lines in it
*/
std::vector<cv::Point> getEndPoints(cv::Mat &img)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> res;
    for (int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++)
    {
        uint8_t *buf = img.ptr(y);
        for (int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++)
        {
            if (buf[x] == 0) continue;
            int iCnt = countNeighborhood(img, x, y);
            if (iCnt == 2) res.push_back(cv::Point(x, y));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

the countNeighborhood can be done with a kernel if you like.
the function getEndPoints returns array of all found endpoints.

P.S. this function works on black (0) background and white (1-255) als lines.